# ASP.NET MVC5 Controller Action only accessible using RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a user registration sequence. To achieve this each method in the controller uses RedirectToAction to pass the flow to the next controller method. The problem is that it is also possible for the user to manually type in the URI and guess the id to open the RegisterAdditionalDetails view for any user.

The [ChildActionOnly] attribute unfortunately also prevents RedirectToAction from invoking the view, so is there another attribute I can use, or is this approach completely wrong and is there a better way to achieve this sort of "registration wizard"?

The best solution I've come up with is to compare the provided id parameter with the logged in user id (works because user is signed in after first step), but that still allows a user to break the wizard flow for themselves.

Relevant controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUser(CreateUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            MemberSince = DateTime.Now,
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Email = model.Email,
            Name = "",
            Street = "",
            City = "",
            PostalCode = "",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            Sex = "Undefined"
        };

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            return RedirectToAction("RegisterAdditionalDetails", "Profile", new { id = user.Id });
        }
        AddErrors(result);

    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterAdditionalDetails(string id)
{
    if (id == null || User.Identity.GetUserId() != id)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(new RegisterAdditionalDetailsViewModel()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        Street = user.Street,
        City = user.City,
        PostalCode = user.PostalCode,
        BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
        Sex = user.Sex,
    });
}
```

Comment: It's okay if the user breaks the website for themselves. What you don't want to happen is any fallout from the webserver for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to expose RegisterAdditionalDetails URL and the view is not that complicated, simply replace

```
return RedirectToAction("RegisterAdditionalDetails", "Profile", new { id = user.Id });
```

this to

```
return await RegisterAdditionalDetails(user.Id);
```

**[Edited]**

Oh, I'm sorry I forgot it's MVC, not WebAPI. long story short, just modify return code of RegisterAdditionalDetails method like:

```
return View("RegisterAdditionalDetails", new RegisterAdditionalDetailsViewModel()
```

Story longer, The ViewEngine will try to find appropriate view by the controller and action name in the `RequestContext`. In this case, The initial action was `CreateUser`, so the ViewEngine will try to find `CreateUser.cshtml` in the Views folder by default. You can specify the 'View' by 'viewName' parameter as above.

It's little bit smelly, but it works (hopefully).

Or you can separate `RegisterAdditionalDetail`'s logic into another method or service, then call it in `CreateUser` method, and return the view with the returned value like this:

```
// in the CreateUser method,
// call separated logic
var viewModel = await GetRegisterAdditionalDetailsViewModelAsync(user.Id);
// and then return a view with specific viewName and model.
return View("RegisterAdditionalDetails", viewModel);
```

Comment: Yes, this works as requested if I put the [ChildActionOnly] attribute on the RegisterAdditionalDetails method. So simple! A good thing too as User.Identity.GetUserId() is not set even if I make the SignIn synchronous (but does work if I first log in and then with a logged in user step through the wizard). Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't appear to work today. I'm getting an error when calling: return await RegisterAdditionalDetails(user.Id);
Error:
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.RegisterAdditionalDetailsViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.CreateUserViewModel '.

Comment: I edited my answer with additional explanation and code. I hope it's acceptable for your needs.

Comment: Returning a view from a POST action could lead to same data being inserted in the database. It is a good practice to use the POST redirect GET pattern to avoid this.